# dc js choropleth map appears invisible

Tags: d3.js, dc.js, crossfilter

I am trying to draw two choropleths ( US states and county) in a page, using dc.js . The us county map is somehow becoming invisible. The dom elements are present, properly with path and fill values, when inspected (as shown in the figure). I'm able to click on those inivisible counties and able to affect the filters as expected. [image]  The fill colors are accurate as per the cross_filtered data. Why is the color fill not happening properly ? What is it missing here ?

```
    d3.json(load_geojson_states){

    <code for states json>


    d3.json(load_geojson_county){

        <define dimensions>
        <define group on dimension>

        usChart_cnt
            .width(1000)
            .height(500)
            .dimension(cnt_dim)
            .group(change_p_sqft_cnt_group)
            .colors(d3.scale.quantize().range(["#E2F2FF", "#C4E4FF", "#9ED2FF", "#81C5FF", "#6BBAFF", "#51AEFF", "#36A2FF", "#1E96FF", "#0089FF", "#0061B5"]))
            .colorDomain([0, 30])
            .colorAccessor(function (d) {   /*console.log(d);*/ return d? d.chng_pct:0; })
            .overlayGeoJson(countyJson.features, "county", function (d) {       return d.properties.FIPS;   })
            .valueAccessor(function(kv) {  //console.log(kv);
                     return kv.value;
            })
            .title(function (d) {
                return "County: " + d.key + "\nChange in Price per SqFt:  " + numberFormat(d.value ? d.value.chng_pct : 0) + "%";
            })


        dc.renderAll();

        }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

This issue is resolved by referring to this post:  [DC.js choropleth map chart CSS conflicting with colouring, no map showing. How can I turn off the fill:none?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41139341/dc-js-choropleth-map-chart-css-conflicting-with-colouring-no-map-showing-how-c)

The whole issue is because the 'county' class gets over-rided with css from dc.js . Upon changing the class name as follows ,i'm seeing the values getting filled up properly :

```
.overlayGeoJson(countyJson.features, "cnty", function (d) {       return d.properties.FIPS;   })
```